# How to capture the named pipe traffic in windows

Tags: windows, pipe

i wanted to check the named pipe which i am using between two of my processes is safe or not. Though many says it is possible to sniff the named pipe traffic. i didn't find any concrete method to capture the named pipe traffic.

Answer (score 5):

You can use "[Pipe Monitor](http://ioninja.com/plugins/pipe-monitor.html)" which lets you see what is flowing through Windows named pipes.

Also, to restrict the access to your named pipe, you can specify a security descriptor for a named pipe when you call the CreateNamedPipe function. The security descriptor controls access to both client and server ends of the named pipe. See [MSDN doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/aa365600(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: It requires buying a subscription. Wish you had mentioned that in your answer

Answer (score 0):

Sysmon Event IDs 17 and 18 are where you'd capture and find this info.

Answer (score -1):

You can use api hooking.
Did you try with process monitor?

Comment: i am not finding any details using process monitor. Regarding api hooking can we do it on the production binaries. i mean using api hooking can the hacker sniff the data.